# Sieve of Sundaram Help

Tags: function-construction

I am attempting to implement the Sieve of Sundaram:

*Start with the list of integers 1,2,...,n. For every pair of integers (i,j) satisfying 1<=i<=j and i+j+2ij<=n, remove the number i+j+2ij from the list. Take all the numbers still in the list: double them and add 1 to each. This results in a list of all the odd primes below 2n+2.*

Here's the code I wrote:

```
sundaram[n_Integer] := [
  Do[i = 1, n, 1,
   Do[j = 1, n, 1,
    If[i + j + 2*j*i <= n, AppendTo[list1, i + j + 2*j*i], Break[]];
    If[MemberQ[list1, i], Break[], AppendTo[list2, 2*i + 1]]
    ]
   ];
  Select[list2]
  ]
```

Since I am trying to teach myself Mathematica, I'm not sure what has gone wrong, these are some errors that are showing up:
[image]

I am unable to make sense of these errors. I'd like to know how I can fix the syntaxes in my module.

Comment: 1) This is not the correct syntax for `Do`. You should read the documentation of `Do` for examples. 2) You need to define `list1` as something before running this, otherwise you are appending to something undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Usually I try to avoid global variables that don't hold long living data.  Especially in this function, which should in this implementation begin with `Block[{list1={},list2={}},etcetc]` instead of just `[etcetc]`...   scoping.  Your `Do[i=1,n,1,stuff]` should be more like `Do[stuff,{i,1,n,1}]` or just `Do[stuff,{i,n}]`.

There's a million ways to do this in Mathematica, all valid depending on use case.  *After getting your implementation to work*, here's a mildly interesting one to look at

> 2Delete[Range@n,Flatten[Table[{i+j+2i j},{j,(Sqrt[1+2n]-1)/2},{i,(n-j)/(1+2j)}],1]]+1

Btw this is an interesting sieve I didn't know about!  Edit: I suppose I'm mostly just expanding on Marius Ladegård Meyer's comment, now that I read this.